# CloudFormation open source equivalent or rolling your own

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, orchestration

Would anybody have any clues as to how AWS CloudFormation works under the hood?

Also, would anybody know an open-source equivalent to AWS CF (and I don't mean tooling that may be using CloudFormation)?

It's clearly a powerful orchestrator, but I'd be keen to explore the inner workings of such tools.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Cloudformation has multiple pre-defined set of schemas for each of the components that are supported. When you upload a Cloudformation template for creating resources, it performs the below steps:

1. It validates the templates against the schema
2. It generates dynamic form for gathering parameters
3. It validates the values of parameters
4. Once it has all it needs, you can click Create to begin with the resource creation
5. Under the hood, it starts creation of resources using the internal coding for which is keeps echoing the status and progress continuously on the console.

We need to understand here that internally Cloudformation in itself is a product that does use AWS SDK/CLI as needed. However, under the hood, it maintains its own data to compare the attributes and resources when you run an update.

An open source alternative to this is `Terraform`. Terraform is the most widely used open source replacement of Cloudformation. Terraform is known for its Cloud independent architecture. Terraform works with multiple clouds with minimal changes in the templates.

The under-the-hood working of terraform involves creation of a `State` file/directory where it stores the current state of any stack identified uniquely by the name provided by the user. Terraform creates resources majorly using Python SDK (boto3) and some other APIs as needed. We need to pass the access key and secrets to the Terraform configuration in order to enable it to access the AWS Cloud environment.

If you are looking to build a smart new alternative, it should be fairly simple considering that AWS strictly follows standard design patterns in its SDK and CLI interface design. This makes it easier to convert template into executable code.

More information about working of Cloudformation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-whatis-howdoesitwork.html)